# How to Authenticate & Authorize a Client-Side Web App using Remote NodeJS API that uses Passport.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, passport.js

As shown in the illustration below, I have a standalone API Project running on a server with a port say `3001`, and I have a Web App running on a server with port say `3002`.

[image: Flow of Web APP to API]

**API on port *3001***, has all the API routes required for the Web App (& mobile apps) to fetch and put data, including Authentication API (Using `passport-local` and `passport-jwt`). In the API side of the project, I have also handled user role authorization, and every routes has list of roles who can access the APIs.

**Example Route**

```
todoRoutes.get('/', 
               requireAuth,
               AuthController.roleAuth(['user','editor','admin']),
               TodoController.getTodos);
```

**Role Authorization API Method in port 3001**

```
exports.roleAuth = function(roles){

    return function(req, res, next){

        var user = req.user;

        User.findById(user._id, function(err, foundUser){

            if(err){
                res.status(422).json({error: 'No user found.'});
                return next(err);
            }

            if(roles.indexOf(foundUser.role) > -1){
                return next();
            }

            res.status(401).json({error: 'You are not authorized to view this content'});
            return next('Unauthorized');

        });
    }
}
```

**Response json after login successfully is like this**

```
{
    "token": "JWT eyJhbGci...",
    "user": {
        "_id": "5986b81d940bab06ddc79b34",
        "email": "myemail@gmail.com",
        "role": "admin"
    }
}
```

Now in **Web App**, I want to use same role authorization and authentication (login), but you see, Web App is not connected to database, for me to make queries like check if the user in session is valid and has the role as in the response it got after login successfully.

**Summary** 
Here are bullet points of what I was looking for in this question:

1. Login on Client-Side Web Application, via Remote API on port 3001 (achieved)
2. Get User Token and other information (*response shown above*) (achieved)
3. Ensure user is authenticated on Client-Side Web App and also remember role of the user loggedin, to use these information for authorization of every routes on Client-side app. In client-side app I have few pages with forms to send data to Server-Side API on port *3002*, these pages are used by two different user with roles *editor* and *admin*.

TIA

Comment: So the API doesn't have authentication but no RBAC, but the webapp wants to implement an RBAC. right?

Comment: API has, authentication and RBAC (for all apis), now web app wants to use the apis and also the RBAC, RBAC for Web app is for controlling views, where as RBAC for API was for controlling the access to controller and read-write data.

Comment: Gotcha! i've added an answer. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 1):

Your authenticating API should return a JWT with guaranteed information (the role) embedded. Further, the token should be made using a secret known to your view APIs.

---

For example, using npm module [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken), sign it like so:

```
token = jwt.sign( {
    exp: Math.floor( Date.now() / 1000 ) + ( 60 * 60 ), // 1 hour
    i: user._id,
    role: user.role
}, "my-secret" );
```

Then, on your view API, use [passport-jwt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-jwt), which both verifies the token and provides you a payload that matches the original object you signed. Use the payload as the user object:

```
passport.use( new JwtStrategy( {
    secretOrKey: "my-secret"

}, ( payload, callback ) => callback( null, payload ) ) );

const authenticate = () =>
    passport.authenticate( "jwt", { session: false, failWithError: true } )
```

At this stage, your user is at minimum authenticated. If you want to restrict a view to certain roles, you would add a second middleware:

```
const assertRole = ( ...roles ) => ( req, res, next ) => 
    req.user && roles.includes( req.user.role ) ? next() : res.sendStatus( 403 ) );

todoRoutes.get("/admin/view1", authenticate, assertRole( "user", "editor", "admin" ), TodoController.getTodos );
```

If your view is going to be need more information about the user, the authentication API will need to provide that, either in the JWT (and thus guaranteed) or outside (not guaranteed, but results in smaller tokens).

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.roleAuth = function(roles){

return function(req, res, next){

    var user = req.user;

    User.findById(user._id, function(err, foundUser){

        if(err){
            res.render('index.html');
        }

        if(roles.indexOf(foundUser.role) > -1){
            res.render('another.html');
        }

        res.render('another2.html');

    });
}
```

}

Comment: I couldn't understand what you meant to say with this piece of code.

Comment: In your questions, you have mentioned that you want to manage your views according to your roles, that what I have done with `res.render`

Comment: The code above is on API Server, and API server does not handle any views, also check how routes are placed on main api server.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that I see this can be done, though not perfectly.

One is to use the primary api endpoint of a particular view. Normally each view has a primary endpoint, and if that endpoint returns an `Unauthorized` / `Forbidden` status, you shouldn't render the view. But this solution has problems and not always there's a primary endpoint matching a view.

Other option is to namespace the routes with roles, like `admin/dashboard` and `users/dashboard`, and the user should have a field describing their role, eg. `user.role`. And before rendering the views, check for the respective role in url and in user object returned by the API.

The second option is preferred and this is what I generally use.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I couldn't understand this how to use this for overall authentication of the app. Can you make me clear on this.

Comment: From your new edits in your question, I understand that you have done role based authentication in API server, and now you want to somehow use it to restrict routes accessible to user in client side. There are many ways to do it. First of all if there's no restriction on client side, the API server should always match the role of user in session with the role required for the endpoint (that you can achieve easily like shown in my answer).
Secondly you can also read the user role from JWT etc. in client side and prevent rendering and form submissions of users of other roles.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the beauty of `JWT`s solve this issue already, or rather can solve your issue with the correct implementation?

All that is required is for you to

1. initialise the `passport-jwt` module in your **WebApp** in the same way you initialise it in your **API**, namely the `secretOrKey` parameter.
2. inspect the `JWT`, specifically the `role` property and allow/reject based on that

Comment: Can you instruct me with sample code structure, i couldn't understand `secretOrKey` part.

Comment: Also can you make me clear on how can i use `passport-jwt` on client side without having to connect to `User` schema, or is this compulsory to have `User` schema on client app as well.