# How to get the equivalent nodejs Requst to CURL command?

Tags: node.js, curl

I have following CURL command

```
curl -u YOUR_API_KEY:x \
 -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
 -X POST \
 -d '{"first_name":"Tony", "kind":"person", "contact_name":"Stark"}' \
 'https://ACCOUNT_NAME.quadernoapp.com/api/contacts.json'
```

I want do this request in NodeJS using the request module. 
This is the code I have written.

```
var options = {
    uri: 'https://ACCOUNT_NAME.quadernoapp.com/api/contacts.json',
    json: true,
    auth: {
      user: 'YOUR_API_KEY'
    }
    data: {"first_name" : "Tonsdfasdy", "kind":"peasdfarson", "contact_name":"Staasdfadfadrk"}
  }

request.post(options, function cb(){})
```

But it is not authenticatd properly. What is the error here?

Answer (score 0):

You're authenticating using HTTP Basic authentication in your `cURL` command, where `username` and `password` are provided with the `-u` option and separated by `:`, so you need to provide your code with the password, like so :

```
var options = {
  uri: 'https://ACCOUNT_NAME.quadernoapp.com/api/contacts.json',
  json: true,
  auth: {
    user: 'YOUR_API_KEY',
    password: 'x'
  },
  body: {
    first_name : "Tonsdfasdy", kind:"peasdfarson", contact_name:"Staasdfadfadrk"
  }
}

request.post(options, function cb(){})
```

And please try to pass your JSON object in an attribute named `body` rather than `data` (it will be transformed to a JSON string thanks to the `json: true`option).

You may also want to check this one : [how to do Auth in node.js client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15986204/how-to-do-auth-in-node-js-client)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Have you tried to get logs from within your callback function : 
`function(err, res, body) {
  if (err) { return console.log(err); }
  console.log(body);
}`

Also, can you please try to send your JSON in an attribute named `body` rather than `data` ? E.g. : `body: {"first_name" : "Tonsdfasdy", "kind":"peasdfarson", "contact_name":"Staasdfadfadrk"}`