# Filling out a 3rd party htacces

Tags: html, node.js, .htaccess, scrape, .htpasswd

I'd like to write a nodejs script that checks every few minutes a 3rd-party website. The only problem is that I have to enter my username and password through a .htpasswd/.htacces prompt. How can I do this with nodejs?

Comment: Have you tried [`http-auth`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-auth#custom-authentication) or possible duplicate of [how to do Auth in node.js client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15986204/how-to-do-auth-in-node-js-client)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It was easy! I just used `http://username:password@www.websiteurl.com` and it worked